# Lifetime conflicts when implementing IntoIterator to iterate over an inner collection

Tags: rust, iterator, unsafe

I've the following struct:

```
pub struct Data<T, IDX: From<usize>> {
    inner: Vec<T>,
    _idx_marker: std::marker::PhantomData<IDX>,
    // other data...
}
```

I want to implement `IntoIterator` for `&Data` and `&mut Data`, which iterates over some inner collection.
Also the iterator not only returns the current entry, but an additional generic `IDX`. 
In the case of `&Data` everything works just fine. But when implementing `IntoIterator` for `&mut Data` I run into the following problem:

```
// impl<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> IntoIterator for &'a Data<T, IDX> ...

// pub struct DataIntoIterator<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> ...

// impl<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> Iterator for DataIntoIterator<'a, T, IDX> ...

impl<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> IntoIterator for &'a mut Data<T, IDX> {
    type Item = (IDX, &'a mut T);
    type IntoIter = DataIntoIteratorMut<'a, T, IDX>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        DataIntoIteratorMut {
            inner: &mut self.inner,
            index: 0,
            __: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

pub struct DataIntoIteratorMut<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> {
    pub inner: &'a mut Vec<T>,
    pub index: usize,
    __: std::marker::PhantomData<IDX>,
}

impl<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> Iterator for DataIntoIteratorMut<'a, T, IDX> {
    type Item = (IDX, &'a mut T);
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(value) = self.inner.get_mut(self.index) // ERROR!
        {
            let ret = Some( (IDX::from(self.index), value) );
            self.index += 1;
            ret
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives the following confusing error message:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements

note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
note: expected `std::iter::Iterator`
         found `std::iter::Iterator`rustc(E0495)
```

This error message makes no sense to me.
I can use unsafe code get the data I want:

```
impl<'a, T, IDX: From<usize>> Iterator for DataIntoIteratorMut<'a, T, IDX> {
    type Item = (IDX, &'a mut T);
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index < self.inner.len() {
            let ptr = self.inner.as_mut_ptr();
            unsafe { // is this dangerous?
                let value: &'a mut T = &mut *ptr.add(self.index);
                let ret = Some( (IDX::from(self.index), value) );
                self.index += 1;
                ret
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles, but I want to avoid unsafe hacks like this. Is there a safe solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't think it's immediately relevant to your problem, but `PhantomData<IDX>` is overly conservative. You probably want `PhantomData<fn() -> IDX>`, since that has the correct `Send`/`Sync` and `Drop` behavior.

Comment: I think this is solved by the answers to [Mutable iterator for Vec<Vec<(K, V)>>](/q/42446844). Specifically, you need to use `slice::IterMut` to implement this iterator safely, because the compiler can't know that every time you index it you get a different non-overlapping `&mut`.

Comment: [Here's one way you might apply the advice from the other question to your problem.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9d2d093102fa18417789137ce4f8b5e) I reused the standard `Enumerate` adapter to manage the index.